# 'Operation' object has no attribute 'compute_gradients' - tensorflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, lstm

I want to clip gradient value when use LSTM model.

I calculate the gradient by using `optimizer.compute_gradients()` and got the error. Here is my code:

```
self.optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lr).minimize(self.loss)

gvs = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)
```

Error message:

> 'Operation' object has no attribute 'compute_gradients'

How to solve this problem or is there any method to clip the value in tensorflow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.optimizer =  tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(self.lr)
self.train_step = self.optimizer.minimize(self.loss)
gvs = self.optimizer.compute_gradients(self.loss)
```